# Como interpretar respuesta de una api en .json graficamente en Joomla

Tags: php, html, api

Hola buenas tengo que consumo una Api que por ejemplo me da este resultado:

[{"idTipo":1,"Tipo":"Refugio juvenil"},{"idTipo":2,"Tipo":"AlbergueJuvenil_Hostel"},{"idTipo":3,"Tipo":"Apto._ApartHotel_Suite"},{"idTipo":4,"Tipo":"Coleg.Mayor/ Resid.Estudiantes"},{"idTipo":5,"Tipo":"Hostal"},{"idTipo":6,"Tipo":"Pensión"},{"idTipo":7,"Tipo":"Hotel"},{"idTipo":9,"Tipo":"Rural"},{"idTipo":10,"Tipo":"Camping"},{"idTipo":11,"Tipo":"Aloj. para extranjeros"},{"idTipo":12,"Tipo":"Consignas"}][{"idTipo":1,"Tipo":"Refugio juvenil"},{"idTipo":2,"Tipo":"AlbergueJuvenil_Hostel"},{"idTipo":3,"Tipo":"Apto._ApartHotel_Suite"},{"idTipo":4,"Tipo":"Coleg.Mayor/ Resid.Estudiantes"},{"idTipo":5,"Tipo":"Hostal"},{"idTipo":6,"Tipo":"Pensión"},{"idTipo":7,"Tipo":"Hotel"},{"idTipo":9,"Tipo":"Rural"},{"idTipo":10,"Tipo":"Camping"},{"idTipo":11,"Tipo":"Aloj. para extranjeros"},{"idTipo":12,"Tipo":"Consignas"}]

Y esto me gustaria interpretarlo graficamente en una pagina de Jomla aunque sea con un modulo libre, Pero no se como interpretar esos datos y convertirlos. Aparte seria como una agenda de noticias , en fin que se haria una llamada a la Api y esta tenfria que mostrar sus resultados pero en una vista mas grafica

Gracias

Comment: ¿y que te impide hacerlo?  Lo siento pero aquí **no hacemos código a medida** (cada vez que digo esto viene otro y da la solución, así que quizás tienes suerte, pero no deberiamos). Lecturas básicas recomendadas: [ask], [tour] y [example]

Comment: me impide que no se la manera de como hacerlo

Comment: Pues contrata a alguien que te lo haga. Esto no es un foro.

Comment: gracias , disculpar solo era una idea generalizada no queria que nadie me hiciera nada

Comment: Me remito a los enlaces que te he puesto antes, que ya te los han dicho en otras ocasiones por lo que veo en tu historial de preguntas. Míratelos y cíñete a sus indicaciones, sino tus preguntas pueden ser cerrradas y si son varias pueden cancelarte o bloquearte el usuario. Tratamos casos concretos que podamos reproducir, donde normalmente el que pregunta aporta código, y no tratamos con software de terceros aunque usen PHP o cualquier lenguaje de programación, lo siento.

Comment: En cuanto a las ideas generalizadas, es otro de los motivos de cierre, pues no aceptamos preguntas cuyas respuestas se basarán en opiniones, pues como he dicho antes, esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas  simplemente.

Comment: Algunos sugieren que este tipo de preguntas se hagan en el [chat del sitio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), puedes probar alli a ver si tienes más suerte, pero como pregunta válida, lo siento, pero no lo es para el sitio.